# What citation style is this? It has numeric reference, title in quotes, "Last, F.F." name style

Tags: publications, writing, citations

A style I'm required to follow, unfortunately unnamed:

> [1]   Last, G.L., Loo, B.F., Mooo, C.C., “My wonderful title” Int. J.
>   Heat Mass Transf., 32(19-21), pp. 234-245, (2001).
>
> [2]   Moobar, A.D. and Been, D., Book about pink ponies, New York:
>   Wonderful publisher, pp. 34–41, (2003).

Features....

- numeric numbering in []s
- *First, L.L.* name style
- article title in quotes
- year in braces at the end

The closest I could find is MLA Seventh edition, but it never does numeric references.

---

To answer some suggestions below: I didn't find a style file with the publisher. And no clear style description exists, other than the examples provided. (There is a few more, but the features I listed are the main thing in common.)

---

Again more information: http://spie.org/x14101.xml#Word is the instructions to follow. They provide an example MS Word file with manually typed citations. While I can use the LATEX file, I already have the paper in .DOC and need a citation style for that. So this is a question of its name.

Comment: What journal or publisher is this from? Many of the styles can be found if you know that information. . . .

Answer (score 2):

The system of referencing using numbers is called the Vancouver system. As alluded to by aeismail in his comment, each journal has some form of style based on this format. Hence, you need to know how the specific journal style works in terms of ordering the different bibliographic fields, for example, author, title, publishing year, journal, volume number, page numbers, doi etc. If no clear style description exists you can try to adhere to the specific style by looking at other published articles that use the same style.

Comment: Also, in some disciplines there might be a BibTeX style file and all you need to do is load this (and maybe something similar exists for other systems too).

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at: http://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/. This website lets you search for a citation style by example, will provide details of styles that are a close match, and let you know how close they are. Hopefully you'll find the csl style you need. Then you can pop the style into Zotero or another referencing package that supports csl styles.